# React Final Form, use <Field/> outside <Form/>

Tags: typescript, react-final-form

is there a way to use  outside  but still connected?

I'm getting Uncaught Error: useField must be used inside of a  component.

I like to reference the Form in Field component

I'm getting Uncaught Error: useField must be used inside of a  component.

when trying to use  outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `<Form/>` sets stuff in React context that `<Field/>` needs.